# $-3 = (3\theta+\sin\theta) \cos(\theta)$ How do I solve this trig equation?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How do I solve the following?

$$-3 = (3\theta+\sin\theta)( \cos\theta)$$

I'm supposed to get to $\theta =2.01692$

calculator use is ok

EDIT:  I ended up just using a TI84 calculator and setting y1 = -3 and y2 = (.....) and finding the intersection points.

Comment: I think this was posted before and closed but I'm not certain...

Comment: It was closed since it wasn't clear if an approx. was ok.  I posted again with the desired outcome.

Comment: Newton's method maybe? Of course, there are multiple solutions.

Comment: There is no analytical solution. Only option is to use numerical methods. Either single point iteration or newtons should suffice.

Comment: I ended up just using a TI84 calculator and setting y1 = -3 and y2 = (.....) and finding the intersection points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, one approach is to use a [*root finding method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm), for example, [*Newton's Method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

We have:

$$f(\theta) = 3 + (3\theta+\sin\theta)( \cos\theta)$$

A plot shows that there is a root around $2$, so we will choose $\theta_0 = 2.5$.

[image]

The Newton-Raphson iteration is given by:

$$\theta_{n+1} = \theta_n - \dfrac{f(\theta_n)}{f'(\theta_n)} = \theta_n - \dfrac{(3 \theta_n+\sin (\theta_n)) \cos (\theta_n)+3}{\cos (\theta_n) (\cos (\theta_n)+3)-\sin (\theta_n) (3 \theta_n + \sin (\theta_n))}$$

- $\theta_0 = 2.5$
- $\theta_1 = 1.97217$
- $\theta_2 = 2.01714$
- $\theta_3 = 2.01692$
- $\theta_4 = 2.01692$

It only took four iterations to converge. You can repeat this using some of the other methods linked above and this can be programmed into most calculators that support such things.

I am not sure what your second statement means.

Comment: I ended up just using a TI84 calculator and setting y1 = -3 and y2 = (.....) and finding the intersection points.

Answer (score 1):

I had good luck with single point iteration.

$$ \theta \rightarrow \arccos\left(-\frac{1}{\theta + \frac{1}{3} \sin \theta} \right) $$

with just ten iterations you can reach the desired values, if you start from 
$\theta=1$.

Just rewrite the expression in terms of $cos \theta = -\frac{3}{3 \theta + \sin \theta}$ and keep evaluating it over and over again with the new values of $\theta$.